# Algorithm to determine direction of undiscovered space

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, path-finding

I have a 2D array of n squares, where my player can only see 2 tiles in each direction of him. I'd like to be able to determine what direction to go by figuring out the direction that will lead me to the most undiscovered squares.

I'm just getting started in pathing algorithms, and I'm unsure what would be a good solution or approach to this problem? Also, assuming I have something like a 13x13 grid, how do I account for optimizing say, one square thats nearby in the corner thats hidden that I have not discovered yet, so I don't go all the way to the other side before searching for the single undiscovered square.

Comment: Sounds like a version of the [travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).

Comment: You can use A* to figure out the path length to a given target square. The other half of the problem is how to decide what makes a square a "good" target. A naive way would just be 0-8, how many undiscovered squares are adjacent. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

Comment: Are you allowed to remember a map of all the squares you’ve discovered so far?

Answer (score -1):

A* may fit your request.

[Here](http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/astar-search-algorithm-in-javascript) is a good sample in JavaScript

Comment: No, it's not. He doesn't know the map!